# Deserialize this in unity

Tags: arrays, json, unity-game-engine

I'm looking to deserialize this in Unity and have had some success, but seem to be stuck on the double arrays. Here is some of the JSON (relevant stuff shown only)

> ```
> {
> "cities": [{
>     "name": "London",
>     "monuments": [{
>             "levels": 15,
>             "objBeingIntroduced": "none"
>         },
>         {
>             "levels": 25,
>             "objBeingIntroduced": "df"
>         }
>     ]
> }],
> "puzzles": [{
>     "puzzleId": 1,
>     "moves": [
>         [{
>                 "x": 3,
>                 "y": 3,
>                 "xInc": 1,
>                 "yInc": 0
>             },
>             {
>                 "x": 5,
>                 "y": 3,
>                 "xInc": -1,
>                 "yInc": 0
>             }
>         ],
>         [{
>                 "x": 4,
>                 "y": 3,
>                 "xInc": 0,
>                 "yInc": 1
>             },
>             {
>                 "x": 4,
>                 "y": 5,
>                 "xInc": 0,
>                 "yInc": -1
>             }
>         ]
>     ],
>     "squares": [{
>             "x": 3,
>             "y": 3,
>             "type": "d"
>         },
>         {
>             "x": 5,
>             "y": 3,
>             "type": "d"
>         },
>         {
>             "x": 4,
>             "y": 5,
>             "type": "d"
>         }
>     ]
> }]
> ```
>
> }

How would you go about deserializing this in JSON in Unity?

I can grab the puzzle section with all the detail except the moves category as that is a double array. Here is what I have so far

```
[System.Serializable]
public class LevelStructure
{
    public int puzzleId;
    public List<Moves> moves = new List<Moves>();
    public Squares[] squares;
}

[System.Serializable]
public class Levels
{
    public LevelStructure[] result;
}

[System.Serializable]
public class Squares
{
    public int x;
    public int y;
    public string type;
}

[System.Serializable]
public class Moves
{
    public Move[] moves;
}

[System.Serializable]
public class Move
{
    public int x;
    public int y;
    public int xInc;
    public int yInc;
}
```

I can't seem to figure out how to do the double arrays like "monuments" and "moves" sections. Any advice would be appreciated on where to go from here.

Since I believe this structure is fine, how do I actually load the json into these classes?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Altho you should really think your structure through and creare your own code, here is what [json2csharp.com](http://json2csharp.com/#) can do for your:

```
public class Monument
{
    public int levels { get; set; }
    public string objBeingIntroduced { get; set; }
}

public class City
{
    public string name { get; set; }
    public List<Monument> monuments { get; set; }
}

public class Square
{
    public int x { get; set; }
    public int y { get; set; }
    public string type { get; set; }
}

public class Puzzle
{
    public int puzzleId { get; set; }
    public List<List<>> moves { get; set; }
    public List<Square> squares { get; set; }
}

public class RootObject
{
    public List<City> cities { get; set; }
    public List<Puzzle> puzzles { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: That looks handy, but how do you load the json into the classes? Specially the 'moves' class.

Comment: For making thks work in Unity you should remove the `{set; get}` everywhere and use fields instead of properties. Also all classes have to be tagged `[Serializable]`

Comment: json2csharp, neat! I did not know about that site before

Comment: @Cypras I suggest not to mess with Unity's serialization, it is very limited, and buggy. All the people I know made their own version. I prefer serializing everything I need into a JSON string and then giving it to unity.